# ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing folder linux

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I've compiled the binary for peer in hyperledger fabric v0.60 but when I run peer node start I get

```
2018-05-18 12:24:56.818 ADT [main] main -> ERRO 001 Cannot run peer because cannot init crypto, missing  folder
```

however the crypto folder does exist in

```
/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thank you

Comment: Are you actually using Fabric v0.6?  It's no longer supported or maintained

Comment: Yes. I need to use it for research purposes

Comment: Why v0.6?  Why not move to the latest version?

Comment: As far as I'm aware 1.0 doesn't use the PBFT consensus protocol which is what I need to test

Comment: @VenomSnake14 did you ever solve this? I'm having the same error on fabric 2.3 "Using the Fabric test network"